# Unable to hide the non-selected options from a multiple select using Chosen plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-chosen

I am using chosen plug in for a multiple select box.
I am trying to display only the already selected values but I am not able to get the required result.

```
<select data-placeholder="Add Names" name="names[]" id="inv" multiple class="chosen-select"  >

    <?php $checked_names=array();
    foreach($names_details as $row) {
        $checked_names[] = $row->names_id;              
    } ?>

    <?php foreach($names as $row) { ?>  
        <option id="invitees_id[]"  value="<?php echo $row->id?>" <?php echo (in_array($row->id, $checked_names ) ? 'selected="selected"': set_select('names[]', $row->id)); ?> >
            <?php echo $row->firstname." ".$row->lastname;?>
        </option>
    <?php } ?>  

</select>
```

This is what I've tried in JS:

1)

```
$('.chosen-select').chosen();
$("#inv").chosen({
    display_disabled_options: true
});
```

2)

```
$("#inv").chosen({
    display_disabled_options: false
});
```

3)

```
$(".chosen-select").chosen({
    display_disabled_options: false
});
```

I didn't get result from any of the options I've tried. Help? Suggestions? Thank You.

Comment: Try adding a "disabled" attribute. "Not selected" and "disabled" are two different things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a "disabled" attribute. "Not selected" and "disabled" are two different things.

```
<option id="invitees_id[]"  value="<?php echo $row->id?>" <?php echo (!in_array($row->id, $checked_invitees ) ? 'disabled="disabled"':set_select('names[]', $row->id)); ?> >
```